# Remove square brackets from child rows in json

Tags: php, arrays, json, square-bracket

I am trying to display the following data on a website :-

```
"daily":[{"dt":1593864000,"sunrise":1593834201,"sunset":1593894929,"temp":{"day":18.47,"min":17.83,"max":18.71,"night":17.83,"eve":18.71,"morn":18.47},"feels_like":{"day":16,"night":13.09,"eve":16.54,"morn":16},"pressure":1006,"humidity":77,"dew_point":14.37,"wind_speed":5.51,"wind_deg":244,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":90,"uvi":7.08}
```

I extract any of the entries except the ones in the weather section as the code I'm using thinks that the weather data is a separate array.

The section of code relevant to displaying the data is :-

```
<span class="min-temperature">&nbsp;Minimum Temperature&nbsp;<?php echo $data->daily[0]->clouds; ?>&deg;C</span><br>
  <span class="min-temperature">&nbsp;Pressure&nbsp;<?php echo $data->daily[0]->weather->id; ?></span>
```

The first line displays data fine but anything within the weather section fails to display anything.

I've seen solutions to remove all the square brackets but its only the brackets surrounding the weather section that is needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to display `$data->daily[0]->weather[0]->id`. BTW let me suggest not using `&nbsp;` in your markup, but control the format with css, keyed on the "min-temperature" class

Comment: This JSON is not valid

Comment: Hi Les, you’re spot on all I needed was to add [0] on to the end of weather and it worked, I’m sure I had tried that already but hey ho , it’s sorted now. I’ll look at the non breaking space during the tidying up process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code below json_decodes and echoes cloud and the weather array. 'hope it helps. please comment. thank you.

```
<?php 

$data=json_decode( '{"daily":{"dt":1593864000,"sunrise":1593834201,"sunset":1593894929,"temp":{"day":18.47,"min":17.83,"max":18.71,"night":17.83,"eve":18.71,"morn":18.47},"feels_like":{"day":16,"night":13.09,"eve":16.54,"morn":16},"pressure":1006,"humidity":77,"dew_point":14.37,"wind_speed":5.51,"wind_deg":244,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":90,"uvi":7.08}}'); # define $data as a stdClass Object
echo $data->daily->clouds;
echo "\n";

# below, weather array is converted into a string
$wa=(array)$data->daily->weather[0];
foreach($wa as $key=> $val){
    echo $key."=".$val."; ";
}

?>
```

Output:

```
90
id=500; main=Rain; description=light rain; icon=10d;
```

[image: (please note this is assumes the edited json data is as originally intended. or please advise. thank you.)]

Comment: Thanks Rupert it was the [0] that was missing off weather that was the problem

Comment: Nice to know it is okay now Paul. Thanks also to Kunai for the cooment below.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `json_decode` in this case to convert a json string to associative array.

```
$data = '{"daily":{"dt":1593864000,"sunrise":1593834201,"sunset":1593894929,"temp":{"day":18.47,"min":17.83,"max":18.71,"night":17.83,"eve":18.71,"morn":18.47},"feels_like":{"day":16,"night":13.09,"eve":16.54,"morn":16},"pressure":1006,"humidity":77,"dew_point":14.37,"wind_speed":5.51,"wind_deg":244,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"clouds":90,"uvi":7.08}}';
$decode = json_decode($data,true);
echo '<pre>';
//print_r($decode);
echo $decode['daily']['clouds'].'<br>';
echo $decode['daily']['uvi'].'<br>';

echo $decode['daily']['weather'][0]['id'].'<br>';
echo $decode['daily']['weather'][0]['main'].'<br>';  //These three are from weather array. 
echo $decode['daily']['weather'][0]['description'].'<br>';
echo '<pre>';
```

**Output**

```
90
7.08
500
Rain
light rain
```

If you want to know how the array indexes works you can make use of `print_r` from the code just remove it from comments.

Comment: Thanks, Kunal. The section of code was just part of the code, the json_decode was already present in the code. (My bad for not posting the full code ) I used print_r as part of testing and that did help me with the breakthrough needed 

Comment: Glad to help you @Paul